# Get Role name in IdentityUserRole 2.0 in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

Before the update of the dll's in the Entity Framework i was able to do this

```
user.Roles.Where(r => r.Role.Name == "Admin").FisrtOrDefault();
```

Now, i can only do r.RoleId, and i can't find a way to retreive the name of thar Role Id. I'm using this in my controllers and in my AuthorizeAttribute class.

Can someone help me here?

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ask the [RoleMananger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613286%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)?

```
RoleManager.Roles.
// or
RoleManager.FindByIdAsync()
// or 
RoleManager.FindByNameAsync()
```

You may want to take some time and learn the new security features in [Asp.Net Security](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security) and [Asp.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity).

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
string id = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email).Id;
IList<string> roleNames=UserManager.GetRoles(id);
```

Comment: how to list it now, i mean in view

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you Neeraj.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had [almost exactly the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771077/retrieve-role-for-a-user-in-the-dal-using-asp-net-identity/) and I solved it like this:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; } // add this to see roles
    public virtual User User { get; set; } // add this to see users
}
```

Now your original code `user.Roles.Where(r => r.Role.Name == "Admin").FirstOrDefault();` will work, which could be handy if you don't have easy access to the `RoleManager` for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to check if a user is in a role you can access it from the IPrincipal.User object in an action

```
User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

Comment: this is in the View, and my question was in the backend...ty anyway