# Get role name out on site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity

I'm trying to show a user profile on my site.

For example: "Rank: Owner"
But I don't know how to display the rank name. This is the code I currently have:

```
<p>@if (Model.Roles.Any() != false)
             {

             <b>@Model.Roles.Any()</b>

             }
             else
             {
                 <b>Member</b>
             }
    </p>
```

But that does only give me this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole]
```

So what do I need to get my role name out?

Comment: `if(Model.Roles.Any()!= null)` is always true. instead `if(Model.Roles.Any())`

Comment: what is a structure of `IdentityUserRole` ?

Comment: @tchelidze I'm doing that because that if it is null then they get member. And it is the ussal structure

Comment: note that `Model.Roles.Any()` can not be null, since `bool` is not nullable type. If `Model` or `Model.Roles` can be null, use  [null propagation ](http://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/) instead `Model?.Roles?.Any()`

Comment: I believe its list of roles. Try creating a method to return string representation of array of roles

Answer (score 0):

First of all @Model.Roles is a list of type [IdentityUserRole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613252%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). So if you wish to see something from that collection you have to iterate it.

```
// this will never generate readable output, it will always print something like this: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole]
<b>@Model.Roles</b>
```

Second: the type [IdentityUserRole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613252%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) doesn't contain any property that contains the rolename. Only the roleid and the userid. I think you have to get those from somewhere else

**[Get Role name in IdentityUserRole 2.0 in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670817/get-role-name-in-identityuserrole-2-0-in-asp-net)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public static class Extension
{
   public static string GetRoleList(this List<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole> roles)
   {
      string rolelist="";
      if(roles.Count==0)
         return "None";
      foreach (var item in roles)
      {
         rolelist+=item+",";
      }
      return rolelist.TrimEnd(',');
   }
}
```

and then use this in view as

```
<b>@Model.Roles.GetRoleList()</b>
```

Comment: When i'm adding it it' says: "Non-invocable member 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole>.Count' cannot be used liek a method.

Comment: Sorry My bad. Remove the method specifiers () from count.

Comment: Then it says: Error 1 Extension method must be static

Comment: Yes that's true. Both class and method needs to be static

Comment: So what should i do then? :3

Comment: please add static modifier in both class and method. I've made necessary changes

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that :/

Comment: Isn't working, it's right to place it into ManageViewModels right?

Comment: Umm, Best will be to create new Class file and then paste it

Comment: Isn't there annother way to get the role name? :3

Comment: There are a few more complicated ways. Is it not showing any output? What are you getting when you break-point in method?